.htaccess deny access to all except one specific file
I have this rule in my root .htaccess file:
# DENY ACCESS TO EVERYTHING INSIDE PHP DIRECTORY
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?someurl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?someurl.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^php - [F]

It denies access to all files inside the "php" directory if accessed outside my server.
How to add one specific file exception, let's call that file "_sharer-socnets.php" using above logic of RewriteCond / RewriteRule?

To deny all but one file you can use this rule:
# DENY ACCESS TO EVERYTHING INSIDE PHP DIRECTORY
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?someurl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?someurl.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/_sharer-socnets\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^php - [F,NC]


Does not work, I got error saying "Internal Server Error, The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." It looks like it block ABSOLUTLY EVERYTHING, cos even if I try to load index.php the same error comes out.

Sorry I had a typo in my answer that I have just fixed. Please try again
